# 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials when Trying to access the TFS API by postamn

Tags: visual-studio, api, visual-studio-2015, tfs, postman

i am getting **401 - Unauthorised: Access is denied due to invalid credentials** error while i am trying to access the TFS API by Postman 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql

this is i am putting in my Postman 
http://apactfs.cbre.com:8080/tfs/applications/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=297,299,300&api-version=1.0

Postman image 
[image]

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: version is 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to **Authorization** tab to choose `Basic Auth` and specify the username and password there:

[image]

Make sure you have enable Basic Auth for your TFS:

[image]

Comment: how to check if basic auth is enabled ?

Comment: thanks man will be needing ur help in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761566/how-to-get-data-in-json-form-by-postman-for-tfs-api