# how to get data in Json form by postman for TFS API?

Tags: json, visual-studio, api, tfs, postman

i am currently using TFS API who's link is 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#byids

currently in my project i want to accees the following workitem 61092 
http://apactfs.cbre.com:8080/tfs/CBRE.APAC.Applications/MRI_SCRUM_GIT/_workitems?_a=edit&id=61092

[image]
and in `Postman` i am hitting the id by this Link By `GET` 
http://apactfs.cbre.com:8080/tfs/cbre.apac.applications/MRI_SCRUM_GIT/_workitems?_a=edit&id=61092&api-version=1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want to get one work item, you should refer to this section of the document:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#get-a-work-item

And in `Postman` you should use the following Link By `GET`

```
http://apactfs.cbre.com:8080/tfs/cbre.apac.applications/_apis/wit/workitems/61092?api-version=1.0
```

Comment: thanks for the help how can i get all the child Workitem/task related to it =61092

Comment: Try `http://apactfs.cbre.com:8080/tfs/cbre.apac.applications/_apis/wit/workitems/61092?$expand=relations&api-version=1.0`, check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-links-and-attachments-1

Comment: thanks man 1 last Question how to get all task's of a workitem ?

Comment: This api should have got all links and attachments for this work item.

Comment: yeah but i am not getting no of hours that user has given to that task of the workitem which i want (hours of all the task's in a workitem) pls help

Comment: try `expand=all` to get all fields' values

Comment: @GiulioVian can i get all the field with there related items ?

Comment: how to get all expand=all with relation http://apactfs.cbre.com:8080/tfs/cbre.apac.applications/_apis/wit/workitems/61092?$expand=relations,all&api-version=1.0 <br/> not working

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT need ur help to get the all the CHILD task(all the fields) in a workitem !!

Comment: @AkhilJain `$expand=all` has already expand all fields, but it doesn't show the empty fields in response. As some fields are not shown on the UI, if it return all fields, there will have lots data.